# Exception Occurred While Sending the Email : - Message Could not connect to SMTP host: 127.0.0.1, port: 25

Tags: java

```
try {
    Log.Info("Sendding Mail,");
    System.out.println("Sendding Mail");
    String host = "127.0.0.1";

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    // Create a default MimeMessage object.
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    // Set From: header field of the header.
    System.out.println(from);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));


    // Set To: header field of the header.
    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));



    // Set Subject: header field
    message.setSubject(subject);

    // Now set the actual message
    message.setText(content, "UTF-8", "html");

    // Send message
    Transport.send(message);
    Log.Info("Mail Sent");
    System.out.println("Mail Sent");

} catch(Exception ex) {
    Log.Error("Exception Occurred While Sending the Email : - Message " + ex.getMessage() + " Stacktrace " + ex.getStackTrace());
    response = false;
}
```

This is my code but I'm getting :

> Exception Occurred While Sending the Email : - Message Could not
>   connect to SMTP host: 127.0.0.1, port: 25 error

please help me.

Comment: Is there an SMTP server running in the machine and listening on port 25? If not, then how do you expect this code to work?

Comment: There must be a server to talk to!